# Cannot open include file: iwscapi.h

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to build an application that requires iwscapi.h. I am getting error:
"Cannot open include file: 'iwscapi.h': No such file or directory". 
Below are my includesthat I have used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <wscapi.h>
#include <iwscapi.h>
```

I have added Wscapi.lib in the linker. My build machine is Windows 7 and I am using VS2005 compiler. I manually searched the file iwscapi.h in C drive but it is missing.
Please let me know what causing this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need the Windows 8 SDK as clearly documented in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155479.aspx), and build for Windows 8 and up.

Comment: @IInspectable I was able to build the code on Win 7 machine itself but I used Visual Studio 2012. Now for running the exe I need to use Windows 8?

Comment: You can build applications targeting later OS versions on a previous OS version, as long as you have the target OS SDK available, and set the appropriate preprocessor macros (see [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx)). Those macros control on which versions of the OS the application can run. In your case, the application requires Windows 8. That's what the [documentation's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155479.aspx) *Minimum supported client/server* are for.